# Multi-column and single-column index on the same column

Tags: mysql, index, performance, optimization, query-performance

I have two indexes on the same column:

1. `store_deleted_idx (store_id, deleted)`
2. `store_idx (store_id)`

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `stores_shoppers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `store_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `store_shopper_id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `country_code` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip_code` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `is_marketing_allowed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_guest` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_spent` decimal(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `orders_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `store_idx` (`store_id`),
  KEY `store_deleted_idx` (`store_id`,`deleted`),
  CONSTRAINT `_stores_shoppers_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `store` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `_stores_shoppers_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `stores_shopper_group` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=56909900 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

My query:

```
SELECT s.*, t.*, g.*
FROM shoppers s
LEFT JOIN shopper_tag t ON s.id = t.shopper_id
LEFT JOIN shopper_group g ON s.group_id = g.id
WHERE s.store_id = '4494' AND (s.deleted = 0 OR s.deleted IS NULL)
ORDER BY s.created_on DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

If I run the `explain`, it shows the query is using only `store_idx` index, but if I remove `store_idx` index and run the `explain`, it shows `store_deleted_idx` is used.

Why isn't `store_deleted_idx` used in the first case?

I can't remove the single-column index.

Comment: Please show us the DDL for the table in question.

Comment: You want to say that using complex index gives higher performance than that with single index? If so use [index hints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html). *Why don't use with store_deleted_idx?* To use index its cardinality is to be high. What's cardinality of `tinyint(1) null`? 11 max (including nulls)... and I think 3 (including nulls) in your case. *I can't remove simple index.* ?? Why? unsufficient rights?

Comment: One more - try to convert your query to `WHERE (s.store_id = '4494' AND s.deleted = 0) OR (s.store_id = '4494' AND s.deleted IS NULL)`.

Comment: No, I want understand why mysql not used with complex index

Comment: @Akina 
`One more - try to convert your query to WHERE (s.store_id = '4494' AND s.deleted = 0) OR (s.store_id = '4494' AND s.deleted IS NULL)` - same result

Comment: @Akina 
If I understand you - index int(11) higher that int(11) + tinyint(3) ?

Comment: *same result* Optimizer needs to choose between simple index (more compact) and complex one (more selective). It choose first index. Why? I think you must investigate the source code of the optimizer to understand it...

Comment: @Akina
Thanks, I now read about index cardinality :-)

Comment: Nevertheless - why you tell *I **can't remove** the single-column index.*

Comment: @Akina

I use it in other queries

Comment: If you delete it server will use complex index. In most cases if you have two indices where the expression of the first index is equal to the prefix of the second one you may freely delete the first one. The less the difference between record size for them the less performance difference. Plus those delete saves disk space and increase INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE operations performance (for UPDATE - only if it affects on these indices).

Comment: Your question is perfectly legitimate as it is but if it's part of the wider problem of how to make this query use the composite index, what I don't understand is why `deleted` is nullable. A row is either deleted (1) or not (0). If you made it non-nullable, you wouldn't have to use the `OR s.deleted IS NULL`, so your condition would be simpler and more likely to use the composite index. Just saying.

Comment: @AndriyM
Yes, I understand that it's better to do the field either 1 or 0. But I can not so easily do it and yes in the table there are many fields that are null :-(

Answer (score 1):

**Get rid of `OR`**

```
(s.deleted = 0 OR s.deleted IS NULL)
```

Make up your mind.  Either use `0` (and make it `NOT NULL`) or use `NULL`.  It is probably better to have

```
TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
```

Until you get rid of the `OR`, an index including `deleted` is not useful.

**Composite index**

After that, `INDEX(deleted, store_id)`, in either order, becomes optimal.

As a rule, `INDEX(a)` is unnecessary if you also have `INDEX(a,b)`.

Even better is

```
INDEX(deleted, store_id,   -- in either order
      created_at)          -- last
```

This will avoid the sorting that is currently necessary.  (See `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`)

**I can't remove the single-column index.**

Do you mean that your fingers don't work?  Your boss will slap your hand if you try?  You don't have permissions?  It comes back when you do remove it?  The `FOREIGN KEY` gets in the way?  What?

**Cardinality**

Fake news.

Within a composite index, cardinality is irrelevant.

When comparing two indexes, cardinality is important, but there are usually better ways to optimize, such as using a composite index.  So, again, fake news.

**Back to the question**

Your experiments showed that either `INDEX(store_id)` or `INDEX(store_id, deleted)` would be used.  Given a choice between the two of them, the Optimizer will pick the smaller one (on the presumption that the amount of effort is slightly less).  Without a choice (ie, when you had deleted the smaller one), the Optimizer happily picked whichever one is left.

So, to avoid wasting disk space, `DROP` the shorter (single-column) `INDEX`.  Meanwhile *this* query will continue to work efficiently.

"Why isn't store_deleted_idx used in the first case?" -- Because of the `OR`.

**More on indexing**

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql discusses how getting all the way through the `WHERE` (after getting rid of `OR`) lets the index get to the `ORDER BY`, and if you get through the `ORDER BY` (by tacking on `created_by`), you can get to `LIMIT`.  *Then* it will read only 10 rows, not the whole table!

Comment: @kostyaR - I talked around it, but failed to address your question.  I now added "Back to the question" section.

Answer (score 0):

I found an explanation in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566211/what-is-cardinality-in-mysql/2566248#2566248):

> Max cardinality: All values are unique
>
> Min cardinality: All values are the same
>
> Some columns are called high-cardinality columns because they have constraints in place (like unique) prohibiting you from putting the same value in every row.
>
> Cardinality is a property which affects the ability to cluster, sort and search data. It is therefore an important measurement for the query planners in DBs, it is a heuristic which they can use to choose the best plans.

I ran `SHOW INDEX FROM table_name`.
My index 'cardinality store_id' is 2380 and
index 'store_deleted_idx' - store_id 2380 and deleted 12

Therefore, MySQL selects the first index!